# Coroutine continue failure in my API script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to re-configure a script for my app and with a new updated version of Unity3d, it seems the `StartCoroutine` requires a stop function, not sure where to place function.

I'm stuck figuring out how to add an if statement that would stop the coroutine and fix the fatal errors.

I've tried to add StopAllCoroutines after StartCoroutine, shown here:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(GetText());
    StopAllCoroutines();
}
```

And here is the full GET-API script:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(GetText());
    StopAllCoroutines();
}

IEnumerator GetText()
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(json);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        // Show results as text
        string myText = www.downloadHandler.text;
        var rate = (double)JToken.Parse(myText).SelectToken("bpi.USD.rate");
        var rate2 = 1 / rate;
        //response  Text.text = rate2.ToString();
        mText = GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();
        mText.text = "BTC: " + rate2.ToString("0.########");
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    Start();
}
```

> Fatal Error: Coroutine continue failure

Comment: Why do you stop the coroutine immediately after starting it? You are starting/stopping the coroutine every `Update` frame, I don't think you want that.

Comment: I could not think of anything else to fix the Coroutine Continue error in Unity. When I run the app in Play Mode, the coroutine continues to run even after I stop the Play Mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're starting a new Coroutine every frame, which is almost certainly a problem (if nothing else it will probably destroy performance).

You're also telling the Coroutine to stop right after starting it, so you're definitely never going to get past the first yield of the Coroutine.

When using Coroutines in general, if you intend only one live instance of the Coroutine to be running at any time, you should keep the reference returned by StartCoroutine and call StopCoroutine on that reference like so:

```
Coroutine Routine = null;

void Example()
{
    if (Routine != null)
    {
        StopCoroutine(Routine);
    }
    Routine = StartCoroutine(ExampleCoroutine());
}

IEnumerator ExampleCoroutine()
{
    // do coroutine

    // end coroutine with:
    Routine = null;
}
```

Make sure that the Monobehaviour that is calling StopCoroutine is the same as the Monobehaviour that called StartCoroutine. Not doing this is probably the most common reason for the error you mention.

Comment: I added the code you provided and made a few changes.

https://pastebin.com/y8t4PD3M

Now when I ran in Play Mode I received this error: https://pastebin.com/6W85iQxZ

Comment: Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: - You are throwing a NotImplementedException every frame (a Monobehaviour's Update method is called every frame if on an enabled object in the scene).

- ExampleCoroutine is not actually a coroutine the way you've written it. Coroutines should be a method that returns an IEnumerator, not a property.

- GetText() is never called. Don't you want that Coroutine to run at some point?

- Example() also doesn't seem to be getting called anywhere.

- As for what's throwing that NullReferenceException, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with that file.